# A Cleverly Disguised Word

Tags: word, pattern, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, connections-puzzle

*<sup>This puzzle can be solved as puzzle on its own, but its solution is also part of [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)'s **[Community Metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45927)**.</sup>*

---

- *The answers to the following nine clues are closely linked.  (Their link is related to wordplay, and not related to the semantic meanings of the solutions.)*
- *The clues are straightforward; they are not [cryptic-clues](/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues).  They are the type of clue you might find in a typical New York Times crossword puzzle.*
- *If you have them all, it should be obvious that they are correct.*
- ***Each clue results in a word/phrase of exactly 10 letters.***
- *Once you have found the nine answers, use them all to find another word, which is the solution to this puzzle.*

  1. Lighting of the candle at both ends
  2. Keeping track of religious works of art
  3. Referencing the creator of Klingons
  4. Being another person generating neologisms
  5. A spasm that just won't go away
  6. An alcoholic's take on a popular cocktail
  7. Studying the night sky with Galileo
  8. Organic fibre separated from its seeds by me
  9. Bullet point on a pigeon enthusiast's profile

Comment: Every time I read #5, I come up with the pun "persisTIC".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are the answers to the clues. (Thanks to Alconja in the Sphinx's Lair and boboquack here, for spotting #7 after I was unable to!)

> 1.  CO-**I**GNITION
>  2.  ICO**N** NOTING
>  3.  **C**ITING COON
>  4.  C**O**INING TOO
>  5.  ON**G**OING TIC
>  6.  GI**N**, NO TONIC
>  7.  NOT**I**CING IO
>  8.  CO**T**TON I GIN
>  9.  INT**O** COOING

These have

> common letters INCOGNITO; and their extra letters, in order ... are also INCOGNITO. (Neat!)

So the intended final answer is

> INCOGNITO (its anagram COGNITION might seem possible but note that the title also hints at INCOGNITO as answer; thanks to GPR for pointing me at this, which I had totally missed).

Comment: In case it's confusing, GIN can be a verb, meaning "to use a gin".

Answer (score 2):

**Possibilities for some of the clues...**

Feels right:

6. An alcoholic's take on a popular cocktail

> **Virgin Mary** ("Virgin" meaning alcohol-free, Bloody Mary being the original)

7. Studying the night sky with Galileo

> **Star gazing**

Speculative/partial

2. Keeping track of religious works of art

> **Record icon**

3. Referencing a Star Trek writer

> Citing Gene

5. A spasm that just won't go away

> endless/nonstop tic

8. Organic fibre separated from its seeds by me

> Whitney gin (Eli Whitney? Cotton gin?)

Comment: You're getting there.  Amusingly, your "feels right" ones are all wrong.  The "speculative" ones each have one word correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand a couple of things on the puzzle, but anyway Here's a partial answer..
**PARTIAL ANSWER**

> Lighting of the candle at both ends-Puzzle
> Referencing a Star Trek writer-[Gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry)
> An alcoholic's take on a popular cocktail- Appetiser
> Studying the night sky with Galileo-Telescope

Now, I am not sure about any of the answers and I also don't find any connections between the words that I found.

Comment: How did you find them?

Comment: @Mithrandir Lighting the candle is a popular puzzle, Galileo invented the telescope, the star trek writer has the link and cocktail part was a bit of a stretch. Like I said, I am pretty sure,some or possibly all of them are wrong