# X Marks the Spot: A Word Tapestry

Tags: word, pattern, wordplay

*This puzzle follows a similar pattern to [this previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/a-cleverly-disguised-word).  I have decided to call this type of puzzle a **Word Tapestry**, since it weaves together the solutions to the various clues.*

---

The answers to each the following clues share all of the letters of the final solution.  In addition, each clue's answer contains one *more* letter, which is *one of* the letters in the final solution.  Combine the *additional* letter from each answer to make a word, which will also contain all the letters *shared* between answers.  That word is your solution.

> *Example:*
>
> - Answer 1:  **HATH**  (additional: **H**, shared: **HAT**)
> - Answer 2:  **A HAT** (additional: **A**, shared: **HAT**)
> - Answer 3:  **THAT**  (additional: **T**, shared: **HAT**)
>
> Final solution: **HAT**

---

#### The clues

1. Not of the crocodile variety?
2. What most criminals do after being caught
3. Certain resident of Delphi, to a believer
4. Forest glow
5. Fats from musk ox, perhaps
6. What Holyfield's doctor might have given him after a famous fight
7. One who evaluates patrons
8. What a lazy accountant might do

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Final answer:

> **TREASURE**  (what one hopes to find at the spot marked by X)

Clue answers *(with help from @Ian MacDonald and @Matt)*:

> **T** - true tears (as opposed to crocodile tears)
>  **R** - rue arrest
>  **E** - a true seer
>  **A** - tree auras
>  **S** - rare suets
>  **U** - ear suture (referring to the fight where Tyson bit off part of his ear)
>  **R** - user rater
>  **E** - reuse rate

Or

> ```
>  TRUE T EARS
>  RUEA R REST
>  ATRU E SEER
>  TREE A URAS
>  RARE S UETS
>  EARS U TURE
>  USER R ATER
>  REUS E RATE
> ```

Comment: The Oracle of Delphi is "a true seer".

Comment: And a lazy accountant might "reuse rate"

Comment: Then also "rare suets" (suet is a fat).

Comment: or rear, depending on where it comes from?